# Centre child div vertically witout knowing parent height

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering in someone knows how to vertically center a child div inside a parent div without knowing the parent divs height?

I have a pinterest style gallery page (images) and on hover I show a div over the top of the images with information about the image. Know because each image could have a different height, I don't know how to center the child content to the middle of the parent div.

I am using jQuery Masonary plugin to create the layout.

Currently I have an outer div containing the image. An inner div with a background colour of white (or whatever) positioned 0,0 and width and height 100%. This all works great and I have been able to center horizontally by simply using text-align: center;

Many thanks!

Comment: Wait .. are you trying to center *vertically* or *horizontally*?

Comment: di you try CSS rules like `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and then applying a CSS `vertical-align: center` ?

Comment: Vertically. I have been able to set horizontal easy enough but I don't know the height of each outer div to be able to set the vertical alignment to the middle

Comment: Yep tried the display code and still aligns to the top of the outer div.

Comment: is child div a set height? If so can do it with CSS

Comment: Child div is 100% of the parent div and the parent div is dynamic.

Comment: Don't you have a code sample? So we can test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work to set it centered both ways. Did not test yet:

```
var ParentW = $("parent-id").width();
var ParentH = $("parent-id").height();
var ChildW = $("child-id").width();
var ChildH = $("child-id").height();
var PosW = (ParentW - ChildW)/2;
var PosH = (ParentH - ChildH)/3;
$("child-id").css({"top":PosH, "left": PosW });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a CSS solution, I think this could work for you.

For example, if you have a layout like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            Lorem ipsum....
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS you should be able to center the `.child` block both horizontally and vertically inside the `.parent` container:

```
.parent {
    /* change values to adjust the top and bottom space used to vertically center */
    padding-top: 33%;
    padding-bottom: 33%;
}

.child {
    width: 50%; /* the width is not mandatory, of course */
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/tgv6Q/). Hope this could be of any help.